# Dislocations,Disclinations Latices, Displacement fields and scaling

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, lattices

I am looking up Frank, and Burger vectors and associated material on dislocation/disclination. It seems straightforward describing a lattice and what dislocation means. It is even possible to restrict broken periodicity only to a line in the modified structure.

However I have a question. If I chose to scale the entire thing say by some factor a, how do I account for an impurity of the form say  $X \rightarrow X + w(X)$ . $w(X)$ here I think is sometimes referred to as a displacement field.

I think what I want to know is how to do a global lattice scaling that takes into account the implications of such a field.

I have done extensive searching around. It seems rather simple but the displacement really puts me down. I have considered stacking and somewhat creating an effectively same problem by gluing together lattices, but it's not working. It turns out that there are cool mathematical implications of this, however I have not found any reference about the scaling problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it is very unclear what you are asking. Perhaps if you can point to something concrete you would like to know, people could give you a better answer. Dislocations and disclinations refer to the ways that an order parameter can have long range order while having localized disturbances. The idea is that the topology of the order parameter allows the order parameter to wrap around in a nonreducible way (in the sense of homotopy) as the disturbance is circumnavigated.

Comment: Scaling, if I understand correctly what you mean by it, has trivial homotopy as an order parameter, so it cannot support these structures.

Comment: I think you are right, although I have a small question but I want to formalize it properly first.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136999/2451

Comment: This is not the question yet, but in the mean time. I thought there could be a way forward if you looked at burger vectors in the language of O-Lattice. To be sure, I don't know much about these: http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_ge/kap_7/backbone/r7_3_1.html .

Comment: I have finally found the opportunity to talk more about this. Essentially I think I might as well just say what I was attempting to do.  I read "Multi-valued Fields" by Kleinert some time ago. A free copy can be found on his site. In chapter 9 he talks about dislocations and disclinations, however I arrived at this by thinking of general relativity.  The idea was to formulate a counting problem. It turns out that in his book he talks about thinking of curvature in terms of dislocations and disclinations. Essentially Einstein-Cartan via tettrads. I had been thinking about lattices.

Comment: So the idea was to formulate Ehrhart's problem on a lattice structure of that form.  This way counting would have meaning, and I can lift the Fourier analogs in this theory into gr. Long story short I don't quite know if I have done  this. So I and someone else tried to just try this in euclidean hyperbolic space, The fact is we don't even know if this has any value.  I thought a little more about if I could achieve the first task by scaling as per Ehrhart theory two separate lattices and using O-lattice language to define curvature. I am sure this is not worth anything, I am confused.

Comment: I tried formalize, and pose the problem but I just don't know how to. I mean it could be (for the second case) thought of as finding discrete sub groups of the mobius group, and defining a scaling operation on such a lattice. at least to start. Then  more . . . .  However in the first case defining such a thing seems ludacris. If it were to be done, then as in the second case the polynomial would be something else and not ehrhart, but then generally bear an additional degree of freedom.

Comment: May be if we can just start by formulating the problem, appropriately then there might be a way forward.